# Amazon SNS sending notification for each verified SES domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I originally had a single verified domain in Amazon SES with a Rule Set that contained an S3 action to save received emails to a S3 bucket along with a SNS topic to send notifications when an email is received. That topic is set up with two subscriptions. One subscription sends me an email notification to my Google mail, the other sends a post to an HTTPS endpoint I have setup. I built an email client to receive those notifications, pull the email from the bucket parse it and display it. Everything is working perfectly...until

I verified 3 additional domains in SES. Using the same Rule Set, for some reason, whenever an email comes in for any of those domains I still get the single email notification to my Google account but now I am getting four identical notifications posting to that endpoint. I assume, one for each domain. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: *"identical notifications"* -- you'll probably want to capture the entire notification, headers and body, and determine precisely how byte-for-byte "identical" they really are.  There should be enough information to pinpoint the problem, but it may be information that's in the notifications that you aren't actively using.

Comment: They are, byte-for-byte, exactly the same. I do not have recipients set up in the rule so that rule is applied to every verified domain. I tried creating a rule set with 4 different actions based on the recipient domain. For example if the domain was example1.com it would put it in a bucket called example1.com then send a notification....and so on for each domain. It made absolutely no difference. It still sent four identical post requests and a single email. It makes no sense.

Comment: Still scratching my head over this one... did you somehow by chance subscribe the https endpoint to the topic more than once?  Is the correct number of subscriptions (2, one email one https) still showing on the SNS topic?